# LSTM for multidimensional data

Tags: lstm

Is there any ML framework that readily supports LSTM for multi-dimentionsal data ?

Best would be in Pytorch. But I don't think the official API supports it and I have found an implementation.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your specific use case? What are you trying to predict and what does the data look like? There is likely existing models available in PyTorch that can be tweaked to support LTSM.